# rigid column and bean not falling correctly

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I created a column tied to a beam that should fall over because of the weight of the beam, however, as seen in the linked video the column falls, but does not topple over.

I tried changing the "shape" in the "Rigid Body Collisions" section to "Convex Hull" as well as to "Sphere" and "Mesh" the results were the same.

https://youtu.be/18qDe29EL4o

How do I get the column to topple over as it would in real life?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the origin "to geometry", going from

[image]

to

[image]

then it will fall as expected:

[image]